# boost.python and qt

Tags: python, qt, boost

i have written a library with some classes that make use of qt object such as QVector, QColor etc, without inheriting from them. Now I would like to make these objects (partially) available to python. I first tried SIP, but this is so poorly documented that I can't even build the example. Now I am trying boost.python, which works fine for standard c++ classes.

However, once I start to include Qt stuff, it still compiles, but fails to import to python. Here is a minimal example:

**testclass.h**

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVector>
#include <QColor>

class testclass
{
public:
    testclass();
    const char* output();
    QVector<double> & data();
    static int x(){return 1;}
    QColor * c();

private:
    QVector<double> v;
};
struct stat;
```

**testclass.cpp**

```
#include "testclass.h"

testclass::testclass()
{

}

const char* testclass::output()
{
    qDebug() << "string";
    return "hello";
}

QVector< double >& testclass::data()
{
    return v;
}

QColor* testclass::c()
{
    return new QColor();
}
```

**testclassBoost.cpp**

```
#include "testclass.h"
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libtestclass)
{
    // Create the Python type object for our extension class and define __init__ function.
    class_<testclass>("testclass", init<>())
    .def("output", &testclass::output)  // Add a regular member function.
    ;
}
```

CMakeList.txt

```
project(boostpythontest)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.45.0)
IF(Boost_FOUND)
  SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
  SET(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
  SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
  FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.45.0 COMPONENTS python)
ELSEIF(NOT Boost_FOUND)
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Unable to find correct Boost version. Did you set BOOST_ROOT?")
ENDIF()

include_directories(${QT_INCLUDES} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} "/usr/include/python2.7")


set(SRCS
  testclass.cpp
  testclassBoost.cpp
)

add_library(testclass SHARED ${SRCS})

target_link_libraries(testclass ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY})
```

now trying to import the resulting library results in the following error:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 27 2011, 14:59:25) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libtestclass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./libtestclass.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6QColor10invalidateEv
```

Interestingly, some qt classes are not problematic. Without the function c() it works fine (no problem with the QVector). What can I do to make this work? I do not intend to use any functions with qt stuff in python, but I would like to use qt in the c++ only part of the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need QtGui for `QColor`, not just QtCore.

Comment: yes, this is the answer, thanks a lot! I replaced ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY} with ${QT_LIBRARYS}
and added set(QT_USE_GUI TRUE)

include(${QT_USE_FILE}). But why could I compile the library and even use it in another c++ program?

Comment: @Felix: AFAIK, ELF shared libraries can be linked with missing symbols, which are then expected to be provided at load. Python didn't load QtGui symbols before trying to load your .so, hence the error at runtime.